# Where can I learn more about the structure of PHP frameworks?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, orm, frameworks

I've used a few PHP frameworks and I can appreciate the simplified ways of communicating with MySQL via ORM, and the separation of data using MVC.  I'm curious though, where can I learn about how these ideas are constructed?  For instance, what goes into making an ORM?  What else goes into an MVC framework and how is it all connected?

Comment: wikipedia has good information on thoese basic knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read more about design patterns, the book "Head First Design Patterns" is very good!

Answer (score 1):

Read the source code of the frameworks you've used. It was written by another PHP coder just like you, in the same language you program in.